# Line Break - React Prop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props

I have a component `<Ren1 text="Line1\nLine2\nLine3" />` ...

```
function Ren1({text}){
  return <p>{text}</p>;
}
export default Ren1
```

How do I add the line break from `\n` from when it comes from the database?

Needed output:

```
Line1
Line2
Line3
```

Thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Split the text prop on "\n" and map the result array into the `p` tag within a `Fragment` with `br` element.

```js
function Ren1({ text }) {
  return (
    <p>
      {text.split("\\n").map((line, index) => (
        <React.Fragment key={index}>
          {line}
          <br />
        </React.Fragment>
      ))}
    </p>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(
  <Ren1 text="Line1\nLine2\nLine3" />,
  rootElement
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.13.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.13.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: This would add paragraph breaks, which might not be what OP wants. Wrapping in a `<React.Fragment key={index}><br />{line}</React.Fragment>` would be a viable alternative.

Answer (score 8):

You can do it without splitting the text value.

First, put curly braces around the text prop when you are passing it:

```
<Text text={"One \n Two \n Three"} />
```

Then use `whiteSpace: "pre-line"` style

```
<div style={{ whiteSpace: "pre-line" }}>{props.text}</div>
```

[sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/heuristic-bas-43bsq?file=/src/Text.js:71-129)

Answer (score 0):

You could create an array containing the actual text lines
with `split` (i.e. `const lines = text.split('\n')`).

Then you could map over this array to render the
lines individually.

`lines.map(line => ...)`